# Using plot_grid (cowplot) to align ggplot and base r plot with the same x limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridview, cowplot

I am trying to plot 2 scatterplots on top of each other, but I want to have the same limits on the x-axis so that the two plots are aligned.

I tried:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 

 geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,10))

plot(1:10)
p2 <- recordPlot()                 

plot_grid(p1,p2,
          labels = 'AUTO',
          hjust = 0, vjust = 1,
          nrow=2)
```

Is there a way to automatically set the x-limits? For example if I were to have another plot (say a barplot with long labels in the y-axis). Can this be achieved?

Comment: base R plotting and ggplot are very different, and cowplot is entirely based on `ggplot2` and using it's grid/grob/geom and so on and on. Note that you need `gridGraphics` to use cowplot with baseR. To your question, I doubt that you would be able to easily do that. I admit I find it hard to understand why you would want to combine ggplot and base R plots in one plot?

Comment: P.S. just make the baseR plot with ggplot. In your example `p2<-ggplot() +geom_point(aes(1:10, 1:10))`

Comment: This was just a toy example, but I am using an R function that plots something I want to have just below my ggplot. Isn't there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe it would help to show the function you are using for plotting and we can try to convert it into a ggplot :) Just an idea.